# Force font size for entire document

Tags: fontsize

I am writing a document for my university, and it requires that the entire document be written in 12pt font (including title, TOC, header, subheaders, references, body text, etc.). Is there a way to force it so that nothing in the document can be a different size?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. It can, but are you sure that the requirement is as bad as you say? Because if yes and if I ever get to see the document, I'll very likely vomit `:(` As for the question: putting `\let\oldfontsize\fontsize\def\fontsize#1#2{\oldfontsize{12}{14}}` before `\begin{document}` should do that, but it's a very very very bad idea.

Comment: Yes, it is that bad (I've lost marks before because my title and headers were too large), and everyone who writes one hates it. Thanks for your help though! For the record, it's this: https://math.uwaterloo.ca/math/current-undergraduates/co-op-information/work-report-guidelines/30-work-report-structure

Comment: @tohecz and OP It is particularly disappointing to see such guidelines issued by a department of mathematics which one might hope would encourage the use of LaTeX, if anybody did. Obviously they are using 'properly formatted' and 'professional' in a some kind of non-standard sense I'm not familiar with.

Comment: @tohecz An answer? Yours seems to me the only sane way to respond to an insane requirement.

Comment: @cfr Waterloo is famous for its "co-operative" education programs where you study for one or two terms and then get a paid internship for a term, usually in industry. The guidelines are for the reports that students must submit after their work terms, and they are designed to conform to business, not academic standards.

Comment: @AlanMunn I'm not convinced that conforms to 'business' standards either. (Do businesses really require everything be in 12pt and double-spaced? Sounds unlikely.) Stuff like the non-indentation etc., that I can completely see. Also no underlining and the way the sectioning is set up. But I'm not at all convinced that 'business' standards rule out have a report title in, say, 14pt font.

Comment: @cfr Hey, I'm not defending the guidelines :). Just pointing out that their source is much more from a business perspective than from an academic one. But double spacing and uniform font size are quite common in e.g. legal documents, for example. They are also widely prevalent in what North American universities expect of student work generally. But the notion of a 'business document' is itself much more ill-defined than that of an academic document.

Comment: @AlanMunn Sure. And the notion of 'an academic document' is pretty hazy, itself. Legal documents have all kinds of weirdnesses, though. I think they are in a class of their own. It is just that it would be nice if a *maths* department at least indicated how to achieve some of that in LaTeX. That's all. It would be nice to see positive encouragement for undergrads using it. (Mostly that seems absent e.g. my university provides training for postgrads but not undergrads, even those that would like to learn.)

Comment: @cfr Waterloo's a weird place in many respects: this isn't the math department, but a whole faculty of mathematics, with 4 separate departments (Applied Math, Combinatorics and Optimization, Pure Math, Statistics and Actuarial Science) plus the school of computer science. And my bet is that the majority of the CS students use Word not LaTeX. And the reports themselves I would suspect have very little math in the majority of them.

Comment: @AlanMunn Ah. I see. It seemed to be under Mathematics so I assumed it was, well, part of Mathematics. But if that's not the case... [It is a shame academia generally isn't more supportive but it is much less unexpected. In my discipline, it is extremely alien to the vast majority, for example, and very, very, very few journals will take it.]

Comment: The following comment isn't meant to *justify* Waterloo's ban on changing font sizes; it's just a guess as to *why* this ban was introduced. I suspect it was introduced in reaction to the habit of many students to play excessively with font sizes (and weights, and shapes). Left to their own devices, too many people succeed admirably in making their documents look like ransom notes. And let's face it: it's not difficult to abuse LaTeX and create documents that look like ransom notes. In such an environment, imposing a complete ban on changing font sizes may have seemed like a good idea...

Comment: Let's face it: **(1)** They make it easy for W@#$ users: **(a)** Sections are simply paragraphs in bold, the level of the section is given by the number of numbers in starts with -- 1. Top section, 1.1. Subsection. **(b)** Whatever you do, you return to the correct size by pressing Ctrl+A and selecting 12pt font. **(2)** As it has been said, they do not care about typography at all (which is said for a top math dept.). **(3)** The _only_ reason I am _slightly_ willing to see is that it easier allows to compare the lengths. But who would care about lengths of math reports?

Comment: @tohecz No one would care about the lengths of math reports, but these *aren't* math reports. They are reports of what students did on the work term in industry. So it's unlikely that most of them will have much math at all.

Answer (score 8):

Adjust all the font size changing macros to mean `\normalsize`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\renewcommand{\tiny}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\small}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\large}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\Large}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\LARGE}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\huge}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\Huge}{\normalsize}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,blindtext}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\title{A Title}
\author{An Author}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

For the most part, this will ensure that all font size switches are "no-ops". Direct font switches using `\fontsize` is still in play.

Note that this does not change any of the math font sizes. However, that wasn't part of the request and it would horrible.

Answer (score 4):

This is among the ugliest things I've ever done, but here you go. We simply modify `\fontsize` to always think it's got `{12}{14.5}` as its arguments.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\let\origfontsize\fontsize
\def\fontsize#1#2{\origfontsize{12}{14.5}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{2ex plus 1ex minus 0.5ex}
\usepackage[small,compact]{titlesec}

\pagestyle{headings}

\title{A Title}
\author{An Author}
\date{\today}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```